# Text header with background

Tags: header-footer

I would like to draw the following image for my resume:

[image]

How to draw this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\colorbox{lightgray}{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\textbf{Research Interests}}}
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Machine Learning
  \item Natural Language Processing
  \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the bullets closer to the box, see the `enumitem` package.